# Strange behaviour while I'm texturing an object using the projection painting technique

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting

I'm working on the `projection paiting` explained on this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eQy5jn9dWrs). My problem is that I have completed the tutorial and it seems that there are no problem,as you can see here :

[image: pic 1]

but this is what happens when I close and reopen blender :

[image: pic 2]

Something does not work. I tried to make two operations to fix the problem,but they didn't do it.

1) I gone under `image/pack image as png` and I packed the textures as `png` but it didn't work. Plus,sometimes `the pack image as png` option appears,sometimes not. why ?

2) I gone under `slots/save all images` but it didn't work

what can I do now ? thanks.

[image]

Comment: The best way to learn in your case is to not worry too much about how to fix whatever went wrong, but to go back and start over. You'll find the error.

Comment: I do it often. I did this the tutorial 3 times already.

Comment: Then there's something wrong with the tutorial. It happens a lot. What version of Blender are you using?

Comment: Blender version 2.77

Comment: For some reason the painted image texture hasn't been saved. Note that UV grid texture is generated and will be saved regardless of whether it was packed or not; but the painting on it *is* dependant on saving. I could reproduce described behaviour only if not saving / packing image before closing Blender.

Comment: That tutorial was using 2.72, so there might be changes since then. I don't understand the purpose of the checkered grid. afaik, that's for transparencies, but you only have one texture, so I wonder why that was used.

Comment: do you have a newer tutorial about the projection painting ? I can do it to learn what's wrong.

Comment: Hello to everyone. I did another tutorial,this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QR5QTgMQQjk ; but I had the same problem. Would someone give a look inside the blender file ?

Comment: I added the blender file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image data is treated separate to 3d model data, you must save the image data as a separate action from saving blender's data.

If an image is saved as an external file, then you need to choose *Image->Save Image* in the UV/Image Editor. If this is the first time you have saved the image you also want to save the blend file so that you also save the location of the image.

If an image is to be saved as a packed image within a blend file, you need to choose *Image->Pack Image*, then save the blend file so the image is saved to disk with the rest of the blend file.

If you alter a packed image, you need to use *Image->Pack As PNG* to update the packed data, then save the blend file to save it to disk.

The *Image->Pack As PNG* menu option is only available when a packed image has been changed.